# Why ingress ignores global-static-ip?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

So I have this Ingress.yaml.
All was fine with it but recently it started giving the wrong ip address and not the static ip .
I don't what happened but i don't think it's the ingress fault.
The node balancer for some reason not using the global static ip :(

does anyone know what it might be.
when i describbe ingress there is no errors.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-static-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    - www.domain.com
    secretName: my-secret
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Is the reserved global static IP `my-static-ip` seen in the output of `gcloud compute addresses list`?

Comment: yes. it's shown and always and says it's reserved but not used. What's weird is that it did work before but suddenly stopped.

Comment: can you delete and recreate the ingress? This should be a relatively quick operation so shouldn't cause too much downtime

Comment: Oh man i have done this 384758934758934 times and new ip every time

Comment: Is there any instance or access config that has not released `my-static-ip` properly?

Comment: @RayLuxembourg Same here. The only solution I found was to manually create a "forwarding rule".